# what is size of this struct?

Tags: c, memory, struct

size of `int` in my system is `4` bytes and `char` is `1` byte ,so I thought size of this `struct` will be `10`(4+6) bytes.

```
struct Riddle {
    int n;
    char s[6];
};
```

but it is `12` bytes(checked with `printf("%d",sizeof(Riddle))`.

this might be a stupid question ,but it really confused me.

can you explain to me how is it possible?

thanks for help.

Comment: struct size is platform dependent. Consult the reference manual for your particular compiler to find out if and how your platform pads bytes in struct layouts.

Comment: The size of the struct is how big it needs to be for an array of same.  That is affected by the alignment requirement of the components of the struct.  In this case I guess the `int` is 4 byte aligned, so the size needs to be a multiple of 4.